# Hide Custom Cursor on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, database-cursor

I have the following code for a custom cursor. I am trying to hide the cursor on mobile,  but I don't know which code I need to use and where I need to paste it. Can someone help me?  Thank you!

```
<div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
    <svg height="10" width="10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
 
  body .cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
body .cursor__ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
}
body .cursor__ball circle {
  fill: #f7f8fa;
    }}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>
const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Listeners
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
}

// Move the cursor
window.CP.exitedLoop(0);function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
    x: e.clientX - 15,
    y: e.clientY - 15 });

  TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
    x: e.clientX - 5,
    y: e.clientY - 7 });

}

// Hover an element
function onMouseHover() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 4 });

}
function onMouseHoverOut() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 1 });

}
</script>
```

Tried to add @media, but didn't know where to paste is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just set display: 'none' for the cursor element

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body .cursor {
        display: 'none'
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is working! Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: no problem buddy, basicly everything is only for mobile need to be in the brackets

Comment: Thanks! I appreciated your help. I have another question:  The cursor, which is a ball, was supposed to grow/scale when hovering over a link, if you see the code, this function is there, but it is not working, do you know what's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but i can't help with that